# Количество потоков приложения

Tags: linux, многопоточность, c++11

В приложении, в процессе работы динамически создаются потоки (например, используя `std::launch::async`). Какие-то потоки создаются, какие-то уже работают, какие-то закрылись.

Можно ли как-то узнать, сколько потоков на данный момент запущено?

Имеется ввиду: есть ли какое-либо API или функция. Ввести переменную под тем же мьютексом и осуществлять подсчет - это можно реализовать без проблем. Но интересует именно другая реализация.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9663422/4827341

Comment: @alexander barakin Ну да... Как вариант, вполне себе ничего и может быть. Оформляйте ответом, приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, можно воспользоваться содержимым [*procfs*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), подсчитав количество вложенных каталогов в каталоге

```
/proc/идентификатор-вашего-процесса/task
```

Comment: А что быстрее будет отрабатывать: подсчет файлов или поиск и чтение из файла информации о потоке?

Comment: точный ответ можно получить лишь после тестирования. учтите, что *procfs* — это псевдо-файловая система. т.е., обращений к диску не будет ни при получении списка псевдо-каталогов, ни при чтении псевдо-файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно прочитать содержимое одного из файлов

`/proc/идентификатор-вашего-процесса/stat`

или

`/proc/идентификатор-вашего-процесса/status`

В этих файлах содержится также и информация о количестве потоков.